# Extend 1d numpy array in multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d numpy array, e.g. a=[10,12,15] and I want to extend it so that I end up with a numpy array b with the shape (3,10,15,20) filled with a so that e.g. b[:,1,1,1] is [10,12,15].
I thought of using np.repeat but it's not clear to me how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tile` will do it for you.  Internally this does a `repeat` for each axis.

```
In [114]: a = np.array([10,12,15])
In [115]: A = np.tile(a.reshape(3,1,1,1),(1,10,15,20))
In [116]: A.shape
Out[116]: (3, 10, 15, 20)
In [117]: A[:,1,1,1]
Out[117]: array([10, 12, 15])
```

For some purposes it might be enough to just do the `reshape` and let `broadcasting` expand the dimensions as needed (without actually expanding memory use).

Comment: Great, thanks ! I would never have found such an excellent solution from the numpy tile reference !

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1800).reshape((10,12,15))
b = np.repeat(a, repeats=5, axis=0).reshape(((3,10,15,20)))
```

You can change axis if you want to repeat in a different fashion. To understand repeat use lower shape for e.g. a(3,5,4) and b (2,3,5,4) and repeat on different axis.